# Java hashmap - put is not working properly?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am using hashmap, but it is not working correctly. I have a class Computing.java, where I have method for adding into hashmap:

```
addIntoMap(String key, String value){

   m_parameters_values.put(key, value);
   }
```

and method for get from hashmap:

```
public void getValueByKey(String key){
        System.out.println("GET "+m_parameters_values.get(key));
    }
```

I am calling theese methods from Main class, but I am not able to be able to get keys, I am still getting null. Do you know why?

Content of class computing (constructors omitted):

```
public void Parse (String args[]) throws Exception{
        Parse(args,true);
    }

    public void Parse(String[] args, boolean throwErrorIfParamenterNotDefined) throws CmdLineException
    {


        int i = 0;

        while (i < args.length)
        {
            // The current string is a parameter name
            String key = args[i].substring(1, args[i].length() - 1).toLowerCase();
            String value = "";
            i++;
            if (i < args.length)
            {
                if (args[i].length() > 0 && args[i] == "-")
                {
                    // The next string is a new parameter, do not nothing
                } else
                {
                    // The next string is a value, read the value and move forward
                    value = args[i];
                    i++;
                }
            }

            if (!m_parameters.containsKey(key))
            {
                if (throwErrorIfParamenterNotDefined)
                {

                    //throw new CmdLineException("Parameter is not allowed.");

                }
                //continue;
            }
            System.out.println("Key: "+key+" value: "+value);
            m_parameters_values.put(key, value);
            //System.out.println("GET "+m_parameters_values.get("provider"));
            }

        // Check that required parameters are present in the command line. 

        for (String key : m_parameters.keySet())
        {
            if (m_parameters.get(key).required() && !m_parameters.get(key).exists())
                throw new CmdLineException("Required parameter is not found.");
        }


    }

    public void getValueByKey(String key){
        System.out.println("GET "+m_parameters_values.get(key));
    }
```

Content of main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Computing comp = new Computing("Computing");    

        cmdLine.Parse(args);
        cmdLine.getValueByKey("convert");
```

Comment: Could you post a bit more code, possibly relevant parts of class `Computing` and use of.

Comment: Because it's not the same map, or because it's not the same key, or because value is null, or because the key was removed. The bug is in your code, not in HashMap.

Comment: HashMap has been around for almost 15 years, longer I suspect than you have been using Java, but you have come to the conclusion it is HashMap which is not working, rather than your understanding of it is incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

print `value` used in `put` method.

Acc. to javadoc:

> A return value of null does not necessarily indicate that the map contains no mapping for the key; it's also possible that the map explicitly maps the key to null.

To be sure, use `containsKey` method to verify if `key` really exists.

use following code in `getValueByKey`; and see if it prints anything:

```
if (m_parameters.containsKey(key))
{
    System.out.println("GET "+m_parameters_values.get(key));
}
```

Comment: you are right. containsKey() will tell if the key exists in map or not. +1

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you haven't tried to debug this in a debugger because many of the lines you have are suspect.

---

```
String key = args[i].substring(1, args[i].length() - 1).toLowerCase();
```

This give you the lower case with the first or last character.  While you might want to drop the first if you assume it starts with `-` but its not clear by you are dropping the last.

---

```
args[i] == "-"
```

This will never be true as they won't be the same object.  Perhaps `"-".equals(args[i])` is what you intended.

---

```
for (String key : m_parameters.keySet())
{
    if (m_parameters.get(key).required() && !m_parameters.get(key).exists())
```

can be simplified as

```
for (ParameterValue pv : m_parameters.values()) {
    if (pv.required() && !pv.exists())
```

I wonder if `exists()` is supposed to have  anything to do with whether its been set or not in `m_parameters_values`

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to say without seeing more code, but if I had to guess, I'd guess that you have more than one instance of the `Computing` class, and you're adding keys to one instance while trying to extract them from another instance.